# How to authenticate on twitter from iphone using asihttp?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, asihttprequest

I used the asihttp library to connect to twitter.

The idea is to send a login request, get the response and extract the session ID/auth code from the response's cookie header. Then you can use that session ID/auth code for consecutive calls.

I don't obtain the auth_code because the authentication fails. how can I fix this?

the code is below:

```c
 - (void) login {
 NSString *username = @"user";
 NSString *password = @"pass";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/sessions?phx=1"];

 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease]; 

 [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value: @"ASIHTTPRequest"];

 [request setPostValue:username forKey:@"session[username_or_email]"];
 [request setPostValue:password forKey:@"session[password]"];

 [request setDelegate: self];
 [request setDidFailSelector: @selector(loginRequestFailed:)];
 [request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(loginRequestFinished:)];

 [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)loginRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
  NSError *error = [request error];
  NSLog(@"login request failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
}

- (void)loginRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   NSString *responseString = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];   
   NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
```

I tried to connect from shell and it works.

```
curl -d 'session[user_or_emai]=user&session[password]=pass' https://twitter.com/sessions
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't scrape twitter.com. It will end with you getting suspended. Instead use the approved API to integrate with Twitter. You can read about how [authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) works with Twitter's API, how you can use [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) to jumpstart authentication with a users password, and the [open source code](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries) to help get you started.